# Format number with multiple dot grouping separators

Tags: java, format, decimalformat

I need to verify if a String displayed is numeric. The format of the value is 123.345.678,99.
I.e., the grouping separators are dots and the decimal separator is a comma.

I've tried the DecimalFormatter where I set the separators:

```
 DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    formatter.setGroupingUsed(true);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(incoming));
```

However, in this case, I'm getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as Number

I've tried also to add

```
formatter.applyPattern("###,###,###.##");
```

but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

I could also use regexp I guess but wanted first to make use of this `DecimalFormatter` if possible.

Comment: I think the method you want is `parse`, not `format`.  They're kind of opposites of each other.

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lose the currency, and just explicily create a new `DecimalFormat` with the relevant symbols. Once you have that, you should use it to **parse** the incoming string, not to **format** it:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

System.out.println(df.parse(stringToTest));
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked :)
Sorry for the 'Selenium' tag I'll remove it.